# Fetching data from 2 mySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables like this:

**Table 1 - Campaigns:**
id, campaignId, name, content, created, clicks

**Table 2 - Campaignareas:**
id, name, campaigns, date, page

**The relevant data for this question:**
In table 1 the campaigns has a campaignId. The id can for example be 1597143541
In table 2 the "campaigns" cell contains info what campaigns are in that area, and what style they have. 
The data looks like this: [[1597143541,"2"],[1597142979,"2"],[1595939599,"2"],[1595939664,"2"]] (the campaign id and what styling the campaign has. In this example all campaigns has style 2).

I need to fetch a result that contains all campaigns, with the name of the campaign areas that contains the campaign. 
The result should look something like this:
**Example 1** *(campaign name - from table 1)*
**area1, area2** *(names of the campaignareas that has the campaign - from table 2)*
**2020-12-24** *(created - from table 1)*
**123** *(clicks - from table 1)*

My initial thought was to do a query that fetches all campaigns, then loop through the result making queries that looks for what campaignareas they are linked to. I think that approach would be too demanding tho, since there could be hundreds of campaigns.

Is there any way to fetch this information in one query?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) the tables

Comment: You have a bad table design problem